# How to split a YAML into multiple files with a proper name

Tags: awk, yaml

I have a valid YAML:

```
---
name: first
metadata: a
---
name: second
metadata: b
---
name: third
metadata: c
```

How can I split it using a one-liner AWK script in files `first.yaml`, `second.yaml` and `third.yaml`? Solution needs to work with any `name`.

Just splitting the file works but I can't figure out how to add proper file names instead of line numbers (`NR`):

```
awk '/\-\-\-/{f=NR".yaml"}; {print >f}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding 1 more solution.

```
awk '
/name:/{
  close(file)
  file=$NF".yaml"
}
file!="" && !/^--/{
  print > (file)
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
prev!=file{
  close(prev)
}
/name:/{
  file=$NF".yaml"
}
file!="" && !/^--/{
  print > (file)
  prev=file
}
' Input_file
```

Sample output file will be:

```
cat first.yaml
name: first
metadata: a
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
prev!=file{               ##Checking condition if prev is NOT equal to file variable then do following.
  close(prev)             ##Closing output file, to avoid too many files opened in back-end by mentioning close(prev) command here.
}                         ##Closing condition prev!=file here.
/name:/{                  ##Checking condition if line has string name: in it then do following.
  file=$NF".yaml"         ##Creating variable named file whose value is $NF(last field of current line) .yaml
}                         ##Closing name: condition here.
file!="" && !/^--/{       ##Checking condition if variable file is NOT NULL AND line is NOT starting with dash then do following.
  print > (file)          ##Printing current line into output file whose name is there in file variable.
  prev=file               ##Setting prev variable whose value is variable file here.
}                         ##Closing BLOCK for file!="" && !/^--/ condition here.
'  Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: This is very close but I'm still getting "makes too many open files" error.

Comment: @Maklaus, I had taken care of it actually(not sure why it is coming), could you please check my EDIT solution once and lemme know then?

Comment: That helps with too many open files. Can also avoid creating prev by doing this: `awk '/name:/{f=$2".yaml"}; {print(f)}; f!="" && !/^---/{print >>(f); close(f)}'`. The only problem now is that if you change the order of name and metadata in one block of the input file the result will miss lines.

Comment: @Maklaus, Could you please try this `awk '/name:/{close(file);file=$NF".yaml"} file!="" && !/^--/{print > (file)}' Input_file` and lemme know if this helps, this doesn't have `prev` variable in it, lemme know if you Happy now :)

Comment: @Maklaus if the order isn't always the same as in the example you provided in your question then, obviously, fix the example in your question so we don't waste more time trying to solve a different problem from the one you actually have.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it simply using the package `yq` :

```
yq -s '.name' file.yml
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/^name:/{close(out); out=$2 ".yaml"} !/^-+$/{print > out}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another:

```
$ awk -v RS="---\n" 'NR>1{f=$2 ".yaml";printf "%s",$0 > f;close(f)}' file
```

Results:

```
$ cat first.yaml
name: first
metadata: a
```

It worked with GNU awk, mawk and busybox awk but produced a leeding empty line on awk version 20121220.

Comment: multi-char RS is a non-POSIX gawk extension so I'm surprised to hear it worked with those non-GNU awks. Are you sure it's not just using a single `-` as the RS? Never do `printf $0`, btw, do `printf "%s", $0` instead - imagine the difference when the input record contains a printf formatting string like `%s`.

Comment: @EdMorton Well, outputs have no leftover `-` in them. And thank for the `printef`fin headsup.

Answer (score -2):

Here is another way:

This is to address if name: is in the middle like many kubernetes yaml files.

```
awk '/^..name:/{file=$2 ".yaml"} !/^-/{temp=temp $0 "\n"} /^-/{print temp>file; close(file); temp=""}' inputFile
```

Please note, this expects the

> name: to start after two spaces.