# Is that possible to create ingresses in batch?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We create around two hundred ingress resources when we deploy the environment to k8s. We see that they are added sequentially in k8s, adding one ingress takes ~5-10 seconds, so adding 200 ingresses took us ~30 minutes.

The code looks like this:
`kubectl apply -n namespace-1 -f file-that-contains-200-ingresses.yml -server-side=true --force-conflicts=true`

Is it possible to speed up that process? Can we do the update of the nginx configuration in one batch?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with `kubectl apply...` and single file since each resource is separate `API` call and needs to go via all checks. You can find more derail description [here](https://github.com/jamiehannaford/what-happens-when-k8s) if you would like to know what is happening when you send create request to `kube-api`.

What I can advise is to split this file with [yq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72087064/15441928) and apply single files in parallel in your `CI`.